# How would I test a $scope.watch (AngularJS) change in Jasmine?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jasmine, angularjs-directive, jasmine-jquery

I've just recently started writing something with AngularJS and I'm not sure how to go about writing a test for this particular thing. I'm building a "Help Request" mode that has different states. So in my controller, I use a $scope.request_mode variable. The different links to activate help requests set that variable to something differently.

Then inside my directive, I'm doing a `$scope.$watch('request_mode', function(){...});` to selectively activate or deactivate things as the request mode changes. The code all works great, but the problem I'm having is with testing. I cannot seem to get Jasmine to pick up the `$scope.$watch` and actually fire anything when it changes.

I'm sure someone has run into this before, so any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have some existing test code we can look at?

Answer (score 97):

In your unit tests you need to **manually** call `$scope.$digest()` or `$scope.$apply()` to trigger `$scope.$watch()`.

Normally in your code you wouldn't have to do this, since directives like `ng-click` do `$rootScope.$apply` for you behind the scenes.

Comment: that needs to be marked as answer, scope.$apply() works for me

Comment: Is it ever the case that $apply has to be called twice?  I.e. once before changing the watched value and once again after, else my expectations are false.  I can't find an example in which someone had called it twice.

Comment: Yes, calling it twice was also necessary for me within one of my tests.