# Execute a $watch in a test, angularjs

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

I have this code in my controller:

```
angular.module('clientApp')
  .controller('UserSettingsAccountCtrl', function ($scope, userFactory) {

    $scope.$watch(function() {
      return userFactory.getUser();
    }, function(value) {
      $scope.user = value;
      console.log($scope.user) //defined when I add scope.$digest() in my test
      }
    });

    console.log($scope.user) //undefined
});
```

It's executed when my controller is instantiated. But in my test it's not. I get user undefined.

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, userFactory) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    var mockUser = {
      userId: 1,
      name: 'Per',
      premium:{
        active:false,
        freeTrial:{
          expired:{
            value:false
          }
        }
      }
    };
    userFactory.setUser(mockUser);
    console.log(userFactory.getUser()); //User is returned
    UserSettingsAccountCtrl = $controller('UserSettingsAccountCtrl', {
      $scope: scope,
    });
  }));

  it('should be ok to start a trial if the trial has not expired and the user is not a premium', function(){
    console.log(scope.user) //undefined
  ...
  });
```

Why is this executed when I run it live but not in my test?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would I test a $scope.watch (AngularJS) change in Jasmine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17112446/how-would-i-test-a-scope-watch-angularjs-change-in-jasmine)

Answer (score 5):

Normally, the watch is triggered from a digest cycle, either at initialization time or as a result of some event. From tests, you need to run a digest cycle manually after changing something that should affect, or be affected by, the scope:

```
$scope.$digest();
```

Comment: Probably in `beforeEach`, as the last line, just after you instantiated your controller. Could you post the relevant parts of your controller to make sure?

Comment: Now I added the relevant parts.

Comment: Hmm, I think this should work. Does `scope` refer to the same variable in `beforeEach` as in `it`? I can't see where it is declared. If you set a breakpoint inside the watch, does it hit?

Comment: Yes, other scopes works so it's the same (generated from yeoman). No, it does not hit the watch.

Comment: Does it _evaluate_ the watch, i.e. does it hit on the `userFactory.getUser()` line?

Comment: I was to fast. It does hit when I add scope.$digest(). But it is still undefined outside the watch. I added two console.logs in my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63501/discussion-between-thomas-and-user1572526).